# Unable to update to gcc5+ and unable to update binutils on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, updates, gcc

I've been trying to update my version of gcc to gcc-5 and above with apt-get, but I keep running into this error message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-6 : Depends: binutils (>= 2.26.1) but 2.26-8ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I try to update binutils, however, I'm told that I'm already on the most up-to-date version.

```
sudo apt-get install binutils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
binutils is already the newest version (2.26-8ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Can anyone provide a fix for me on how I can work around this?

Comment: Please run `sudo apt -f install`

Comment: *How* are you trying to upgrade gcc? gcc-5.3.1 should be the default already for Xenial; for gcc-6 did you enable a PPA?

Comment: The default for me was gcc-4.8, I've been trying to update it with just `sudo apt-get install gcc-6`

Comment: The default for me was gcc-4.8, I've been trying to update it with just `sudo apt-get install gcc-6`